# Show hidden element on hover another

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying when hover the image and the title, the hidden content to be visible. I did something with hover the outer div, but now if I hover on blank space or the paragraph the effect is the same. How to affect the hidden element when the image and the title are hovered? Maybe I am doing all wrong.

```css
.box {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image>a:after {
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.box:hover .image>a:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box:hover .details {
  top: 30%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x170">
    </a>
  </div>

  <h1 class="title">
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </h1>

  <div class="details">
    <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="summary">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain your question better, what need to show on title and image hover? the hidden link only?

Comment: the div details with the background

Comment: With your current html, it is only possible to do that hovering image with css. Due to the fact that title is after image, you cannot target that with css on hover. You would have to change up your html

Answer (score 2):

**You must restructure your HTML**

I've placed the `.image` and `.details` inside another `div` and added the hover event to the new `div`, not only the `.box`

Try this:

```css
.box {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image>a:after {
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.box:hover .hoverEffect:hover .image>a:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box:hover .hoverEffect:hover .details {
  top: 30%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="hoverEffect">
     <div class="image">
       <a href="#">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x170">
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="details">
       <a href="#">Hidden link</a>
     </div>
     <h1 class="title">
       <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
     </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="summary">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working on hover the title, title must be in hoverEffect div ?

Comment: @xAos Yeah! Just place the `.title` inside the `.hoverEffect`

Comment: What is `.box:hover .hoverEffect:hover`? there is no need to do both. Just use hoverEffect

Comment: @Huangism Well, if he end up using the `.hoverEffect` in a different structure, he don't want to inherit the previous styles from it... But you are right, if there is just this structure, `.hoverEffect:hover` will work!

Answer (score 1):

You should target the div class that is the parent of the link tag, in this case, class= `details`

by default :

```
.details {

display: none; 

}

While on Hover state

.details{
display : block; 

}
```

Comment: In my case that div is with opacity: 0, and on hover is opacity:1, but I want that to be only on hover image and title.